# I need help adding the outputs of a for loop in C

Tags: c

I'm making a code that takes an integer, counts up to the integer, then adds all of the numbers counting up to the integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int i = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Please enter a number:");
    scanf("%i", &i);
    for( a = 1; a <= i; a = a + 1 ) {
        printf("%i\n", a);
    }
        sum = sum + a;
        printf("The total is %i",a);

   return 0;
}
```

It seems to be adding 1 to whatever the input is.

I want it to add all of the numbers that are produced not just the first

Thanks!

EDIT

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int i = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Please enter a number:");
    scanf("%i", &i);
    for( a = 1; a <= i; ++a ) {
        printf("%i\n", a);
        sum = sum + a;
    }
    printf("The total is %i",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks! That is exactly what I wanted to do. I didn't understand that "sum" needed to be part of the for loop to change correctly.

Comment: Don't spam tags! C++ is not C is not C++. And format this mess properly.

Comment: I used suggested tags, sorry

Comment: `sum = sum + a;` move into inside for-loop. `printf("The total is %i",a);` --> `printf("The total is %i", sum);`

Comment: `a = a + 1` -> `++a` - saves on the typing

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding so sorry if the format is terrible.

Comment: @Scrowba copy all the code you just posted in your post and press `Ctrl` + `k`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your summation is outside of the for-loop here:

```
   for( a = 1; a <= i; a++ ) {
        printf("%i\n", a);
    }
    sum += a;
    printf("The total is %i",a);
```

What this does is print that statement multiple times, then do the sum once.

What you want is this:

```
    for( a = 1; a <= i; a++ ) {
        printf("%i\n", a);
        sum += a;
    }
```

Also, if you'd like to print the sum, you want `printf("The total is %i\n", sum);`
rather than `printf("The total is %i", a);`.